# How to make new column by subsetting only text in the rows from an existing column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get a new column 'Species' from the example data below, which should contain only the characters from the column 'Sample'.

```
Sample GermD    OD GermDD 
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> 
 1 TP_126     2  4.20      2 
 2 TP_126     2  4.35      2 
 3 TP_124     2  3.87      2 
 4 TP_124    NA  4.33     10 
 5 NP_120     2  4.92      2 
 6 NP_120     2  3.78      2 
 7 LO_100     2  4.05      2
```

I am trying the following code:

```
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Species = strsplit(Sample, split="_"))
```

The desires result should look like this.

```
Sample GermD    OD GermDD Species
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> 
 1 TP_126     2  4.20      2 TP
 2 TP_126     2  4.35      2 TP
 3 TP_124     2  3.87      2 TP
 4 TP_124    NA  4.33     10 TP
 5 NP_120     2  4.92      2 NP
 6 NP_120     2  3.78      2 NP
 7 LO_100     2  4.05      2 LO
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** We can use `str_extract` to extract the upper case letters (`[A-Z]+`) at the start (`^`) of the string in 'Sample' column

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(Species = str_extract(Sample, "^[A-Z]+"))
#   Sample GermD   OD GermDD Species
#1 TP_126     2 4.20      2      TP
#2 TP_126     2 4.35      2      TP
#3 TP_124     2 3.87      2      TP
#4 TP_124    NA 4.33     10      TP
#5 NP_120     2 4.92      2      NP
#6 NP_120     2 3.78      2      NP
#7 LO_100     2 4.05      2      LO
```

---

**2)** Or using `str_remove` the remove the substring after the `_` (including `_`)

```
df %>%
     mutate(Species = str_remove(Sample, "_.*"))
```

---

**3)** With `strsplit`, the output is a `list` of `vectors`, so we need to extract the first component from the `list`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
  mutate(Species = strsplit(Sample, split="_") %>%
                   map_chr(first))
#   Sample GermD   OD GermDD Species
#1 TP_126     2 4.20      2      TP
#2 TP_126     2 4.35      2      TP
#3 TP_124     2 3.87      2      TP
#4 TP_124    NA 4.33     10      TP
#5 NP_120     2 4.92      2      NP
#6 NP_120     2 3.78      2      NP
#7 LO_100     2 4.05      2      LO
```

---

**4)** Or we can use `separate` and then remove the second column

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   separate(Sample, into = c('Species', "Other"), remove = FALSE) %>% 
   select(-Other)
```

---

**5)** Or using `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   extract(Sample, into =  'Species', "^([^_]+)_.*", remove = FALSE)
```

---

**6)** In `base R`, we can do with `substr` and it should be very fast assuming that we know the positions of the substring to extract.  Here, based on the example, it is the first two characters

```
df$Species <- substr(df$Species, 1, 2)
```

**7)** Or we can use `read.table/read.csv` from `base R` and provide the `sep` argument as `_`

```
df$Species <- read.table(text = df$Sample, sep="_", header = FALSE)$V1
```

**8)** Or another option with `strsplit` from `base R`

```
df$Species <-  sapply(strsplit(df$Sample, "_"), `[[`, 1)
```

**9)** Or with `trimws` from `base R`

```
df$Species <- trimws(df$Sample, whitespace = "_.*")
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Sample = c("TP_126", "TP_126", "TP_124", "TP_124", 
"NP_120", "NP_120", "LO_100"), GermD = c(2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 
2L, 2L), OD = c(4.2, 4.35, 3.87, 4.33, 4.92, 3.78, 4.05), GermDD = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for qick  and multiple ways to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Species = sub('_.*', '', Sample))
```

Output:

```
  Sample GermD   OD GermDD Species
1 TP_126     2 4.20      2      TP
2 TP_126     2 4.35      2      TP
3 TP_124     2 3.87      2      TP
4 TP_124    NA 4.33     10      TP
5 NP_120     2 4.92      2      NP
6 NP_120     2 3.78      2      NP
7 LO_100     2 4.05      2      LO
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for qick soulution.